# In an electron beam or electron in vacuum, is the magnetic dipole orientation of individual electrons theoretically able to take any direction?

Tags: electrons

In atomic orbital, two orientations are allowed from selection rules. For electrons in a vacuum, is the orientation restricted from taking an arbitrary (continuous)direction?

Comment: yes, at least in vacuum. If you define vacuum as empty isotropic space, then magnetic dipole must be able to take any orientation, otherwise you have anisotropy.

Comment: By the way in atoms, as far as I remember, the spins of electrons in the same orbital must be anti-aligned, but that still means that they can point in any direction (together), at least as long as we ignore spin-orbit coupling.

Comment: Thank you. I tried finding the relevant information online, but nothing I could find was explicit. Would this be continuous in 3 dimensions, affected by uncertainty and other (possibly virtual?) particles.

Comment: 1) Ucertainty only comes into play once you start doing measurements. Evolution of the wavefunction is determenistic. 2) The 'any direction' bit is tautological here. Defne what you mean by vacuum. Usually one of the definitions there is 'spherical symmetry', so yes, in a spherically symmetric system the spin of your electron can point in any direction (continuous in 3d) ... because of spherical symmetry, i.e. because rotating the spin, by definition, does not change electron energy, and thus there is no 'energetically preferred direction'